# React: Dynamic route not re-rendering correctly

Tags: reactjs, state, render, react-props

[Codesandbox Repo](https://codesandbox.io/s/93wjv9jkp4)

Learning about dynamic routes with `react router 4` and while doing so decided to refactor a function component into a class component. The reason behind this, and correct me if I'm wrong, is that the `TopNavSub` component is getting information from `react router 4` from `this.props.match.params.<var>` and choosing what to render.

To me this sounds like a change in state. The only thing that has me doubting this is that the state will NEVER change on the same route and will ALWAYS be different for each route so I'm not sure if this is the same as handling state or not. For example, `/mac` will only map items in the `mac` array etc.

I was told using `this.props` directly inside of `this.state` is a poor choice and to instead use `componentWillReceiveProps()` but the React team seems to feel poorly about this, [UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops), and nevertheless it solved nothing.

**TLDR;**
So the problem here is that after refactoring, my data only shows up for the first initial route and no matter which route is chosen afterward will only show the initial route data chosen unless refreshed (`f5`).

### TopNavSub.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// data
import { subNavLinks } from './navigationData';

class TopNavSub extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      navLinks        : { ...subNavLinks },
      product         : this.props.match.params.product,
      currentProduct  : Object.keys(subNavLinks).filter(subNavLinksKey => subNavLinksKey === this.props.match.params.product),
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      (!this.state.navLinks)
      ?
        null
      :
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.navLinks[this.state.product].map(product => {
              return (
                <li key={ product }>{ product }</li>
              )
            })
          }
        </ul>
    )
  }
};

export default TopNavSub;
```

### navigationData.js

```
export const subNavLinks = {
  mac: ['MacBook', 'MacBook Air', 'MacBook Pro', 'iMac', 'iMac Pro', 'Mac Pro', 'Mac Mini', 'Accessories', 'High Sierra', 'Compare'],
  ipad: ['iPad Pro', 'iPad', 'iPad Mini 4', 'iOS 11', 'Accessories', 'Compare'],
  iphone: ['iPhone X', 'iPhone 8', 'iPhone 7', 'iPhone 6s', 'iPhone SE', 'iOS 11', 'Accessories', 'Compare'],
  watch: ['Apple Watch 3', 'Apple Watch Nike+', 'Apple Watch Hermes', 'Apple Watch Edition', 'Apple Watch 1', 'Watch OS', 'Bands', 'Accessories', 'Compare'],
  tv: ['Apple TV 4k', 'Apple TV', 'TV App', 'Accessories', 'Compare'],
  music: ['Apple Music', 'iTunes', 'HomePod', 'iPod Touch', 'Music Accessories', 'Gift Cards'],
  support: ['Apple doesn\'t support anything older than iOS11']
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem either with `componentWillReceiveProps` or, if you want to future-proof it, with the new static `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

```
class TopNavSub extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //This could be extracted to avoid repetition, I'm copy-pasting it
    const currentProduct = Object.keys(subNavLinks)
      .filter(subNavLinksKey => subNavLinksKey === this.props.match.params.product);
    this.state = {
      navLinks: subNavLinks[currentProduct[0]],
      product: this.props.match.params.product,
      currentProduct
    }
  }

  //IMPORTANT: USE EITHER ONE OR THE OTHER
  //I wrote both options for demonstration purposes

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    const currentProduct = Object.keys(subNavLinks)
      .filter(subNavLinksKey => subNavLinksKey === nextProps.match.params.product);
    this.setState({
      product: nextProps.match.params.product,
      navLinks: subNavLinks[currentProduct[0]],
      currentProduct
    });
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    const currentProduct = Object.keys(subNavLinks)
      .filter(subNavLinksKey => subNavLinksKey === nextProps.match.params.product);
    return {
      product: nextProps.match.params.product,
      navLinks: subNavLinks[currentProduct[0]],
      currentProduct
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      (!this.state.navLinks)
        ?
        null
        :
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.navLinks.map(product => {
              return (
                <li key={product}>{product}</li>
              )
            })
          }
        </ul>
    )
  }
};
```

**UPDATE**

About your second question, a good general rule is that if you don't need to handle user input events or hold external data (like data from a backend API), you ("""PROBABLY""") don't need component state. In this case, you're deriving your entire state from props and not doing any event handling, so you could write this component simply as a function like this:

```
const TopNavSub = props => {

    //Since you're using ES6 you can change filter for find to get a single element instead of an array
    const currentProduct = Object.keys(subNavLinks)
        .find(subNavLinksKey => subNavLinksKey === props.match.params.product);
    const navLinks = subNavLinks[currentProduct];

    return (
        (!navLinks)
        ?
            null
        :
            <ul>
            {
                navLinks.map(product => (li key={product}>{product}</li>))
            }
            </ul>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this and especially showing me how to use `getDerivedStateFromProps`. I'd also like to know if you can answer my second question. Is this a proper use case for `state` or would it be just fine to use a function component and map over an array?

Comment: @BrandonBenefield answer updated, I hope that solves your doubts